# Adding lombok dependency and @Slf4j does not let use logger

Tags: java, lombok

I want to use logger from Lombok. I added `@Slf4j` annotation, added dependency and it says that it cannot resolve symbol `log`. `Error:(5, 1) java: package org.slf4j does not exist`

```java
package a;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("lala");
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>a</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Your are simply missing the slf4j API. You need to add it as a dependency. :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You also need to add slf4j itself as a dependency to your project by including it in your pom file. All lombok features in the `lombok.extern` package share this property: They help you use a library that is *NOT* already available out of the box as part of java itself, and for all of them, lombok does not inherently include any of these dependencies.

Should be as simple as adding the following block to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.26</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This worked for me. Although in a spring boot, I just added lombok and it worked. In a standalone project I needed to add sl4j along with lombok. Maybe Spring Boot automatically gets all lombok's extern packages or something.

Comment: @theprogrammer I believe spring boot included slf4j, specifically.

Comment: When we include spring-boot-starter-web or spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency then slf4j comes automatically with them.

Comment: Actually springboot provides implementation of Slf4j for you. When you add lombok to apps or modules without springboot - you don't have the implementation provided.

Comment: I was working in my SpringBoot project few weeks (no slf4j in pom) and one day I started getting the same exception during compilation in IDE. Maven packaging was working correctly. I had to remove all IntelliJ generated files from project and import project (from pom) from scratch.

Comment: In spring boot "spring-boot-starter"  includes this dependency. Other starters such as spring-boot-starter-web or spring-boot-starter-data-jpa add spring-boot-starter as a dependency.

Comment: Lombok is just code gen. Does not add other dependancies, which is a good thing

Answer (score 3):

I tried adding slf4j-api as a dependency as rzwitserloot suggested above, but that did not work for me. Adding it as a plugin in my build.gradle file did, though:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '4.1.6'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to install the Lombok plugin in IntelliJ(IDE) if you want IntelliJ to recognize Lombok annotations. and restart your IDE to reflact the changes.

Comment: The asker made absolutely no mention of intellij, and the error makes entirely clear that lombok is working fine, but the slf4j dependency isn't there, thus proving this answer is irrelevant.

Comment: This problem is IDE-agnostic.

Comment: Issue is not with intellij. It is a compilation error issue